# Error when connect android to facebook (Can't login with other account)

Tags: android, facebook

I make my app following the link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/ . It work for me. But only login by my facebook account (My acc that registered with ID).

could you let me how to login my android app by an other account facebook?

thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Put SandBox Mode of your facebook app to off. Visit http://developers.facebook.com/apps/

Answer (score 0):

Please check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

I think it some android key hash issue.